# Editing Navigation Pane in Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So this is my actual first day using Bootstrap and I know very very little about HTML and CCS and I am quite lost. I am working with a code template provided by someone in my department with actual knowledge in this field, but unfortunately they are not currently reachable for questions so I am on my own. I managed to successfully edit most of the code on the main page I am starting with, however, the whole top navigation bar seems to only be contained within the line **{{GCb-nav-yourfile-eng}}**

The instructions about this line say: **Make a copy. Don't edit this file! Then, point to the new file on your template.**

Could anyone help me understand how I would go about making a new file, and "pointing to it" on my template?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Lets see your code